# Data validation in cell of datagridview control

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I am using datagridview control and in this grid user can edit the value of a fixed column.
i want user only can write numaric values (e.g. 1, 2, 443 etc)

I am not sure at which event of datagridview i have to write this code and what is the code to trap values